# Custom SMTP setting from database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, smtp

Usually in rails we can config the smtp settings like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "anythingworks",
:user_name            => "mygmailaddress@gmail.com",
:password             => "somePW",
:authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

But I need several connections from database value to be set as smtp and also if no value in database the default smtp settings should be used.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set it based on the database value, e.g.:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => Setting.find_by(key: :smtp_address)&.value || 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "anythingworks",
:user_name            => "mygmailaddress@gmail.com",
:password             => "somePW",
:authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

This assumes you have a database table called "settings" with `key` and `value` columns so you can set any generic config in it, one config item per record. And an ActiveRecord class Setting to access  it.

It will fall back to the hard-coded value if the setting isn't present or the value is null.

The other thing is to make sure this config code is established at a point in the boot cycle when ActiveRecord is already present. You could put it in `config/initializers/mail.rb` for example.

Comment: If no value in the database it should use the default settings.

Comment: Are you loading this settings in a initializer file? If so, this file and the query is only loaded when the app loads and you are not able to switch smtp settings while the app is running. Anyone a solution for that ?

Comment: if settings failed which smtp will be used?

Comment: What do you mean by failed? The code above shows you how you can set a fallback address and you can do same for port etc.

Comment: If the user changed his password but in database it will be using old database. How does the error message should be sent to the user using email?

Comment: That's a whole other question

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: I can't in comments here because you keep expanding the scope of your original question. If you start a new question with a specific problem, someone will probably answer it.